# How to clone jQueryUI draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have some jquery draggable objects which are located in a content slider which has multiple pages. These objects are dragged out of the content slider pages and into an 'answer' box which is located outside the slider. This works up until you change pages in the content slider, the answers then 'disappear' out of the answer box until you return to the page in the slider that they were originally on. I need to find a way to create a 'copy' of the draggable object that will stay in the answer box even when the page changes in the slider.

After doing some research I found the helper: clone option but can't seem to get it to stay in the answer box once it's been cloned. Another option I looked at was moving the draggable to a new container using 'appendTo' outside the slider once it had been dropped in the answer box - this again came with it's own problems. I really don't know what to do any more with this after having spent multiple hours trying to fix it!

The code and a screenshot are below... thanks in advance!

Javascript/jQuery

```
// initialisation for all things regarding the drag and drop.
function init_dragDrop(){
    // setup draggable interface
    $(".answer").draggable({ snap: ".destinationBox", snapMode: "inner", revert: "invalid"});
    $( ".destinationBox" ).droppable({

        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var matchedQuestion = null;
            var droppedQuestion = $(this).prevAll(".question:first").html();

            $.each(questionList, function(){
                if(this.body ===  droppedQuestion){
                    matchedQuestion = this;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            var draggedAnswer = $(ui.draggable[0]); 
            matchedQuestion._onCorrect = function(){draggedAnswer.css("backgroundColor", "green");  questionList[++currentQuestion].enable();} 
            matchedQuestion._onIncorrect = function() {
                draggedAnswer.css("backgroundColor", "red");    

            //resets answer to original position in the runbook, and revoves red background color
            $("#reset").click(function () {
                draggedAnswer.animate({
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    top: "0px",
                    left: "0px"
                });
            });
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="questionDiv">                      
<div class="question textbox" id="q1">1. Assemble the Crisis Management Team</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>
 <div class="question textbox" id="q2">i. Set up the emergency conference line</div><div class="destinationBox"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-switcher" id="answerDiv3" >

        <h2>Key Contacts</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><strong>Contact</strong></p></td>
                    <td><p><strong>Telephone Number</strong></p></td>
                    <td><p><strong>Email Address</strong></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Managing Director</p></td>
                    <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox answer a1">0123456789</div></td>
                    <td><div class="dragDropSmallBox answer a2">M.D@acme.com</div></td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I believe helper is just the outline of the object being dragged so a user knows where it is located on the screen during drag. When set to clone it clones the object being dragged and is removed on drop.